# How to remove space from table cells in an HTML table

Tags: html, freemarker

I have been playing around with FreeMarker and html. In my `.freemarker` file I get a list of numbers. I am using a table to display those numbers. I want them to display horizontally one after another. Right now they leave a big space in the middle. I just want them to be next to each other separated by a comma. I know this is more of an HTML question than Freemarker but I wanted to mention how I was getting my numbers.

```
<table style="text-align: center; background-color: #fcc;    
padding: 6px; font-family: Verdana,sans-serif; width: 80%;">

  <tr>
     <#list failedIds as id>
        <td>${id}</td>
     </#list>

  </tr>
</table>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw your comment on @Luiz's post that states that you want the row to wrap after getting to a certain length. It would be relatively difficult to get a table row to wrap (it's not really what tables are meant for), so here is a solution that achieves what you're looking for by using `span`s instead of using a table. You can see that the row wraps into a new one when it exceeds the dimensions of its `div` container.

Again, this is using entirely inline styles as your comment on @wi_marti's answer requests.

**Live Demo:**

```html
<div style="background-color: #fcc;    
padding: 6px; font-family: Verdana,sans-serif; width: 30%;">
      <span>id,</span>
      <span>id,</span>
      <span>id,</span>
      <span>id,</span>
      <span>id,</span>
      <span>id,</span>
      <span>id,</span>
      <span>id,</span>
      <span>id,</span>
      <span>id,</span>
      <span>id,</span>
      <span>id,</span>
      <span>id,</span>
      <span>id,</span>
      <span>id,</span>
      <span>id,</span>
      <span>id,</span>
      <span>id,</span>
      <span>id,</span>
      <span>id,</span>
      <span>id</span>
</div>
```

Your final Freemarker code might then look something like this:

```
<div style="background-color: #fcc;    
padding: 6px; font-family: Verdana,sans-serif; width: 30%;">
 <#list failedIds as id>
    <span>${id},</span>
 </#list>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `width: 80%` from your `table` style and the `id`s will be displayed one right next to another. This is because by removing the width from the table, we are allowing it to collapse all that extra space and only use up the width that is needed.

If you need that `80%` width as part of your design, you can wrap it in a `div` with `width: 80%`. Since you specified that you didn't want to use external CSS, all the following styles are inline.

**Live Demo:**

```html
<div style="background: gray; width: 80%">
  <table style="text-align: center; background-color: #fcc;    
padding: 6px; font-family: Verdana,sans-serif;">
    <tr>
      <td>id,</td>
      <td>id,</td>
      <td>id,</td>
      <td>id,</td>
      <td>id,</td>
      <td>id</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you by any chance know in this sepcidic example how would be the best approach to check when that row has reached a limit. What I am trying to say is that I do not what many numbers I will get so if I get too many numbers I do not want a way to long row. Is there a way to start a new row once one of them has reached a certain width?

Comment: @danilo Please see my [other answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32705143/2234742), which shows a different approach that uses `span`s for layout instead of a table.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the code that I wrote. Seems to work the way you need it.

I just changed the width property from table tag to a div tag, if you need to keep the width of the elements.

```html
<div style="width:80%">
  <table style="text-align: center; background-color: #fcc;    
  padding: 6px; font-family: Verdana,sans-serif;">

    <tr>
       <#list failedIds as id>
          <td>${id},</td>
       </#list>

    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try some CSS:

```
table {
border-collapse: collapse;
border-spacing: 0;
padding: 0;
}

table td, 
table th{
padding: 0; 
}
```

Comment: for this specific case I do not want to use css.